# Select distinct values based column keys placed in different table

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL I am facing a wall. I was looking for solution but could not find anything which would match my case. I understand how joins working. My question is: Is it possible to do a `SELECT` based on result from different `SELECT`?

For clarifying I have 2 `tables` and 1 `view`:

`report_type` table:

```
id | name       | view_name
-------------------------------
1  | citizens   | citizens_report
```

`report_filter` table:

```
id | name        | filter_column
-------------------------------
1  | City        | city
2  | Nationality | nationality
```

`citizens_report` view:

```
id | city     | nationality
-------------------------------
1  | Boston   | American
2  | London   | British
3  | London   | Spanish
4  | Paris    | French
5  | Paris    | French
6  | Boston   | German
7  | New York | American
```

For `raportId = 1` I need to look for dynamic view based on result from: `report_type` table which will be `citizens_report` - so here is first step where I need to build query with result of it and than I need to create unions of filters based on `citizens_report` view.

**Expected result:**

```
filter      | option
----------------------------
city        | Boston
city        | London
city        | Paris
city        | New York
nationality | French
nationality | German
nationality | American
nationality | British
nationality | Spanish
```

I doesn't have to be in any specific order (might be `ORDER BY ASC`). In any language I can create map where key is equal `filter` and `option` is added to array.

Each step I can do with separate query and in any programming language I can call for next one, but could it be done in one query?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your expected result please (not just a definition of the filters to be applied)

Comment: Sure, let me update question